# HTML Select Box, remove option through javascript 'None' option appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML Select Box

```
<select id="orderByItem" name="orderByItem">

    <option selected="" value="Status">Status</option>
    <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>

</select>
```

'Status' option is selected.  Now when I remove the 'ABCD' option through javascript it gets replaced by None

This is the javascript I use

```
$("#orderByItem option[value='ABCD']").remove();
```

I am not sure how 'None' gets into the select, and this is causing major problems.

Comment: Do you want to select ABCD automatically when you remove Status?

Comment: *Has* to be a 3rd-party/external script. Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2L7tk73z/

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/1q97q8z6/1/

HTML

```
<select id="orderByItem" name="orderByItem">
    <option selected="" value="Status">Status</option>
    <option  value="Status2">Status2</option>
    <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="but" id="but" Value="click"/>
```

JS

```
$( "#but" ).click(function() {
  $("#orderByItem option[value='ABCD']").remove();
   $("#orderByItem").get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
    var tempVal = $("#orderByItem").val();
  alert(tempVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("orderByItem");
x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
```

Reference [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp)

Comment: please add some explnanation of your code, showing what it does and how it solves the problem. This will help others in the future who see your answer.